# Cannot start cgconfig on Centos 6.5 : cannot mount cpuset to /cgroup/cpuset: Invalid argument

Tags: centos6.5, cgroup

I'd like to try docker-io on Centos 6.5 but the cgconfig daemon will not start:

```
/etc/init.d/cgconfig restart
Stopping cgconfig service:                                 [  OK  ]
Starting cgconfig service: Error: cannot mount cpuset to /cgroup/cpuset: Invalid argument
/sbin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup mounting failed
Failed to parse /etc/cgconfig.conf or /etc/cgconfig.d      [FAILED]
```

Contents of cgconfig.conf

```
mount {
    cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
    cpu = /cgroup/cpu;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
#   memory  = /cgroup/memory;
    devices = /cgroup/devices;
    freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
    net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
    blkio   = /cgroup/blkio;
}
```

The suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183063/docker-on-rhel-6-cgroup-mounting-failing) did not help

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -l /cgroup
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  1 08:34 cpuacct
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  1 08:25 cpuset
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  1 08:37 devices
-bash-4.1$
```

**UPDATE**

The Centos 6.5 server is a Virtualized server running Virtuozzo (A Media Temple DV). It seems there would need to be some changes in the Virtuozzo provisioning of the server which the hosting company is not prepared to do. Apparently Virtuozzo *does* support running docker in Centos 7 but that's not something I am going to pursue. More info [here](https://openvz.org/Docker_inside_CT). Bottom line is the Kernel the server is running is missing some modules / config which docker needs in order to run. In my case, this is not worth doing.

Comment: Why are you trying to use CentOS 6?

Comment: Centos 6.5 is what the client's target server has and cannot be changed easily.

Answer (score 3):

The Centos 6.5 server is a Virtualized server running Virtuozzo (A Media Temple DV). It seems there would need to be some changes in the Virtuozzo provisioning of the server which the hosting company is not prepared to do. Apparently Virtuozzo does support running docker in Centos 7 but that's not something I am going to pursue. More info [here](https://openvz.org/Docker_inside_CT). Bottom line is the Kernel the server is running is missing some modules / config which docker needs in order to run.